# How to get Passport set up?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I am using Mongoose through [mongoose-simpledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-simpledb). It is just a small layer over Mongoose that allows me to make data models in their own files in a folder called `dbmodels`. I have an `auth.js` file to handle authentication based on some tutorials. Contents:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var db = require('mongoose-simpledb').db;

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password'}, 
    function(username, password, done) {
        db.user.findOne({ email: username }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.password != password) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.user.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

module.exports = passport;
```

I also have this route set up:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    successRedirect: '/user'
}));
```

I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm really irritated with it.

What am I doing wrong here? I have a database with a dummy user in it. When I log in with the credentials, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT1zp.png

### Edit

I have my model set up in `user.js` in `dbmodels`, which is in my app's root folder. Here are the contents:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose-simpledb').Types.ObjectId;

exports.schema = {
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  // TODO: Should these be strings?
  birthday: {
    date: Number,
    month: Number,
    year: Number,
  },
  phone: String
}
```

I have tried changing the casing between `user` and `User` when doing the lookup.

The `auth.js` file is in the root folder as well, along with `app.js`, which contains my database initialization at the very top:

```
var db = simpledb.init({connectionString: '<MongoLab URL>'}, function(err, db) {
    console.log("Connected to database.");
});
```

The `console.log` prints to console before I try to log in.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your passport setup at first look, but the error you are getting is definitely a problem with your access to mongodb. Im not familiar with mongoose-simpledb but it looks like you dont have a model named user declared anywhere.

Comment: Please show the code where you call `simpledb.init` and where that is at in relation to your passport code you show here. Please also show your User model file that is being loaded by simpledb.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure all the model properties get constructor casing when added to `db` since they are technically constructors for model objects. Make sure you're model isn't loaded at `db.User` instead of `db.user` which is what you appear to be accessing.

Comment: @AlexFord Just added more info in the original question.

Comment: @Antrikshy at the time you are calling `db.User.findOne` try logging out the value of `db.modelsLoaded`. If this is set to false still then the models are not actually loaded. Also do this inside the initializer where you log "Connected to database." Instead log out `db.modelsLoaded`. If that one says true but the one where you're calling `findOne` says false, then you've identified a race condition.

Comment: If they both say true, debug and inspect the `db` object at that point. The only properties on that object should be the `modelsLoaded` property and your models. That's it. Check to see if you see any other properties besides `modelsLoaded`.

Comment: If `modelsLoaded` is true at the time you're calling `findOne` but there are no other properties attached to the object, then your model file is not being loaded properly. If that's the case, reply here and we can debug further to find out why.

Comment: In the `init` callback, I print out `modelsLoaded`. It prints true. Then I get `OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite \`user\` model once compiled.` From what I gather this should not happen if I'm only using mongoose-simpledb and not defining any schema manually, correct?. Full error: http://i.imgur.com/TolmVOz.png

Comment: This is slightly off topic, but your usage of password checking here is a supperrrr bad idea. You're storing the password in plain text, and checking it in plain text (really bad idea). If you're looking to just add auth into your app really easily, you might just wanna try express-stormpath -- it does all this stuff and is wayy easier: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/quickstart.html

Comment: @rdegges I know. It would have been easy enough to drop in encryption at a later point. I was doing the plain text password only for testing purposes. I did end up going with Stormpath.

Comment: Ah, interesting. You should answer your question then and mention stormpath. Will help future people =)

Comment: Yes. I was planning to once I was sure I'm going with it. I would still like to learn how to use Passport because for bigger projects (I'm doing a class project), Stormpath seems really expensive. Do you know of similar alternatives for Express?